# C# WPF FolderBrowserDialog - Unable to retrieve the root folder

Tags: c#, wpf, folderbrowserdialog

I am using the FolderBrowserDialog to select the Folder where user can save file. While opening the folder browse dialog, application get crashed and raised below exception.

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve the root folder.
   at System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at TestApp.GenerateExcelReport()
```

Users are using the applications from cloud as My application is launched on Citrix Environment. Hence not all the users has facing this issue but few of them are facing.

```
string folderPath = "X:\\Reports";
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}

FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
folderDialog.SelectedPath = folderPath;
DialogResult dialogResult = folderDialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    folderPath = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Kindly suggest what can be the root cause of getting this issue while showing the FolderBrowseDialog. Also, suggest the potential fixes to prevent this exception.

Thanks & Regards,

Hiren Lad

Comment: I assume X is a network drive. Perhaps it isn't connected or recognized as connected?

Comment: It appears that Directory.CreateDirectory doesn't throw. That method returns a value, see what that is. Is it a network mapped drive? Try not to set the SelectedPath property. See if you have this Key and Value in the registry: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system` -> `"EnableLinkedConnections"=[DWORD]:00000001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs for me when the folder `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` doesn't exist. Creating that folder resolved the issue. Note that File Explorer may show a Desktop folder in `%USERPROFILE%` even if Desktop doesn't actually exist. You can verify whether Desktop exists by running `dir %USERPROFILE%` in `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but the fix for this issue might be if you set the **RootFolder** property of **FolderBrowserDialog** other than the default **RootFolder**.
e.g

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
folderDialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
```